# Proxing ghost blog as subpage /blog from digitalocean on external server using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, host, ghost-blog

I would like to redirect my ghost blog on my other website to achieve ghost blog displaying like this: https://kasacja-aut.pl/blog

Host where the website is stored: https://dhosting.pl/

The server of this domain doesn't support the Node.js, ghost is set up correctly on digitalocean and running but I don't know if the nginx configuration is set correctly.

The domain:https://kasacja-aut.pl is actually proxied via cloudflare and I thinking if I should add any DNS records to it? Beacuse I didn't add any.

[Nginx configuration on digitalocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyfYt.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this?